# Apply a SharpDX Effect to a MediaCapture Stream

Tags: c#, camera, microsoft-metro, effect, sharpdx

I'm trying to apply effects to a video stream in a Windows 8 Metro app. I'm aware of MFT and the `AddEffectAsync`method for the `MediaCapture` class. However I don't know much C++ and dont' feel very comfortable writing my own MFT drivers.

So my hope was to be able to (1) capture the stream of the camera, (2) apply a SharpDX effect to it, and then (3) output the resulting stream to a xaml object on the Metro app. I've already seen [this](http://advertboy.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/custom-effects-ripple-effect-pixel-shader/) site and haven't found the tutorials very helpful considering they involve a lot of C++ code (even if some of them are just wrappers). Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting answer on the MSDN forums. It's not an ideal answer, but it's what I'd been fearing all along.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/f3a6934e-df7a-44da-bfd8-7b95d494ff43/#90690f89-e57d-4043-9881-60fcc587f736